# The profile group 'ProfileGroupPersonal' has not been defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I need to implement Membership Form authentication in MVC. I have created ProfileCommon manually with a Profile Group as well. Now I'm getting this error while creating the user:

> Error:The profile group 'ProfileGroupPersonal' has not been defined.

Here is My Code of ProfileCommon.cs

```
public class ProfileGroupPersonal : System.Web.Profile.ProfileGroupBase
{
    public virtual string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("UserName")));
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue("UserName", value);
        }
     }
}
public class ProfileCommon : System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase
{
    public virtual ProfileGroupPersonal Personal
    {
        get
        {
            return ((ProfileGroupPersonal)(this.GetProfileGroup("Personal")));                
        }
    }

    public virtual ProfileCommon GetProfile(string username)
    {
          return Create(username)  as ProfileCommon;
    }
 }

   ProfileCommon p = new ProfileCommon();
   ProfileCommon profile = p.GetProfile(userName);                
   profile.Personal.UserName = userName;
```

My web.config code:

```
  <profile inherits="FormAuthentication.Models.ProfileCommon" >      
   <providers>
     <clear />        
     <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="Test"/>
  </providers>      
  </profile>
```